# Web Serial API: how to flush and get length of data in buffer?

Tags: javascript, web-serial-api

Is it possible to test whether data is available in the input stream (port.readable)?
And how can it be flushed (read until ...? `cancel()` a reader?)?

---

Docs:

- https://web.dev/serial/ -> https://developer.chrome.com/articles/serial/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SerialPort
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Serial